# In the Justice League episode "A Knight of Shadows", who was Mordred thinking about?

Tags: dc, character-identification, dc-animated-universe, justice-league

In the episode [A Knight of Shadows](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/A_Knight_of_Shadows) from the [Justice League (2001)](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Justice_League_(animated_series)) animated series, the Justice League and Etrigan were trying to find [Morgaine Le Fay](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Morgaine_Le_Fay), to prevent her from finding [a powerful magical object](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Philosopher%27s_Stone) she was looking for.

Around the middle of the episode, J'onn suggests that he could try to locate her telepathically, before doing so. But Morgaine finds out.

> Morgaine: Someone is reaching out to my mind, attempting to find me.
>
> Mordred *(smiling enthusiastically)*: Is it... him... ?
>
> Morgaine: No. A mere amateur. He has no idea who he's dealing with.

Her son [Mordred](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Mordred) was thinking about someone. But who?

It didn't sound like it could be Jason Blood nor Etrigan. If they were able to use telepathy, they wouldn't wait for J'onn to do it (nor would they let him try, considering the consequences of attempting such a deed against a sorceress such as Morgaine).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Likely Merlin. At the beginning of the episode, he's the one who binds Jason Blood to the demon Etrigan, after Jason betrayed Camelot.

Merlin opposed Morgaine in that universe, especially by hiding the Philosopher's Stone. He knows to beware of rogue feys. His line

> All my great dreams are undone in the name of thy tainted love.

likely refers to the legend of Viviane imprisoning him in a cave/tower/rock (depending on the versions) after he taught her the spell, even if he knew how powerful it was; but he couldn't help it, since he was deeply in love with her. Viviane wanted to keep Merlin for herself.

Merlin is also a very powerful wizard, both in-universe and in the actual myth. Morgaine is not stupid, and might deem J'onn a "mere amateur" when compared to Merlin. Although all his powers aren't shown, it's possible he had a "tracking spell" of sorts, which Morgaine could have thought of.

Then again, he *is* supposed to be dead, but it's Merlin. You never know with that guy, which could explain Mordred's surprise.

Comment: Out of curiosity... isn't Merlin saying "in the name of thy tainted love"? I have a feeling he's using old pronouns, considering the era in which it was happening.

Comment: @Clockwork I checked on IMDb and they transcript it as such, indeed. Will have to work on those ears of mine :^)

Comment: These old pronouns are hard to hear though. I had to turn the sound up to better understand what Merlin was saying.